# Getting information from the cookie made by FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I used this in C#:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userID, chkPersistCookie.Checked)
```

to create a cookie for my web app.

I need to know how to get the userID back from the cookie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get user Id you just need to access the principal. For more [read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649204.aspx)

```
  HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

If you want to get it from the cookie, the cookie can be read as(I don't recommend this):

```
  HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
```